# Syntax for curl commands in Python

Tags: python, api, put, canvas-lms

I'm developing Python scripts for the automated grading of assignments using CanvasAPI, an API wrapper in Python for the Canvas learning management platform. In studying the documentation, I can successfully issue curl commands in Python for a few parameters. For example, this conversion below is for grading a single submission:

[Curl command per the Canvas API docs](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/submissions.html#method.submissions_api.update):

```
PUT /api/v1/courses/:course_id/assignments/:assignment_id/submissions/:user_id
```

with

```
 submission[posted_grade]
```

[Turns into this via the CanvasAPI Python wrapper](https://canvasapi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/submission-ref.html#canvasapi.submission.Submission.edit):

```
edit(submission={'posted_grade': 'grade'})
```

Where I'm running into difficulties is the more complex parameter for rubrics. Using the same PUT request as above, the syntax in the [documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/submissions.html#method.submissions_api.update) is as follows:

```
rubric_assessment[criterion_id][points]
```

For which I have:

```
edit(rubric_assessment[{'id': 'criterion_9980'},{'points', '37'}])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021528-29488-1eagfyw.k8hw", line 39, in <module>
    submission = assignment.get_submission(10370)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\assignment.py", line 203, in get_submission
    response = self._requester.request(
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\canvasapi\requester.py", line 255, in request
    raise ResourceDoesNotExist("Not Found")
canvasapi.exceptions.ResourceDoesNotExist: Not Found
```

I suspect I'm fouling up the syntax somewhere along the line. Any suggestions? All help much appreciated.

Comment: try `edit(rubric_assessment={'criterion_9980':{'points': '37'}})` - That's a bunch of changes to yours, so, `rubric_assessment` is now a parameter name to the function with the value being a dictionary, and `criterion_9980` is used as a key to the first dictionary, and the value is a secondary dictionary with a single key of `points` and value of `37`.

Comment: That did it! Many thanks!